# mongodb sharding Collection(?)

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, mongoose, sharding

Is it possible to have different collections in sharded machines? For example the nodeA to have the collection: rolesA, nodeB the collection rolesB and so one, **but** the mongo router to handle **transparently** for my code. In other words to query the roleA without need to know that it's store to the nodeA?

The reason i am asking is that a have a large collection with around 100GB so i have to options:

1. To shard the large collection let's say to 5 nodes
2. To split the large collection to 10K collections in a single node

My queries are $sum aggregations. Right now i am using the second approace so every aggregation query use exactly one collection. The perfomance is by far good < 1 second, but in a production environment the CPU  is always 100%
With the approach 1. the load will be balanced by i am worrying about the response time

Comment: Well, [MongoDB sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/) does what you are describing. You need to choose correct shard key to make sure 1 request goes only 1 node. Btw: Since you need to perform `$sum` aggregation, think about [Materialized Views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/materialized-views/) with precalculated results.

Comment: @Valijon thanks for your response this is what I am using right now: the 10k collections is the result of $merge but in this case since this run on the master, the collections will be hosted in the master node

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have different collections in sharded machines?

In a sharded cluster a database can have number of sharded and unsharded collections. You can decide which collections need to be sharded (distribute a collection's data across shards). A collection is sharded based upon the [Shard Key](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/). Shard key determines how the collection data will be distributed across the shards. The shard key is also important in the read operation performance.

> For example the nodeA to have the collection: rolesA, nodeB the
>   collection rolesB and so on..

You cannot specify that a specific collection's data be stored on a specific shard. Sharding is about distributing a collection's data among multiple shards.

> ...the mongo router to handle transparently for my code.

A `mongos` (the router) receives all the queries in a sharded cluster before routing to specific shard(s). When you submit a query, it is like submitting a query to a standalone server, the syntax is same; it is transparent to the application (or code). The router determines which shards the query must visit to get your data.

If you query's filter criteria has the shard key, then the router will determine the specific shard(s) to target (and without the shard key in the query filter criteria the query will be routed to all shards in the cluster).

> 1. To shard the large collection let's say to 5 nodes

You can distribute a large collection's data in cluster with 5 shards (or more as the data grows - this is called as horizontal scaling).

---

Finally, I tried to answer some of your questions about sharding. Also, please browse the referenced links below for complete information.

References:

- [Advantages of
  Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#advantages-of-sharding)
- [Considerations Before Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#considerations-before-sharding)
- [Sharding Strategy](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#sharding-strategy)
- [FAQ: Sharding with MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/sharding/)